# Beta of options based strategy

Tags: options, portfolio-management, beta

This is probably a simple/dumb question, but I am not getting it.

As per GMO's recent Insight:

> Second, as can be inferred from Exhibit 1, put writing strategies have
>   a low beta to the equity market` and they are able to collect elevated
>   premiums during market sell offs due to enhanced demand for insurance
>   in these periods.
>
> ***`This is mechanical: At-the-money put writing strategies have a delta of approximately 0.5, so a low beta to the market is guaranteed.***

[image]

From that Exhibit, I can see pretty high correlation and close to 1 beta. How can a low beta to the market be guaranteed? how are the authors measuring the beta?

**EDIT**

Alex, as per your suggestions I tried to replicate the graphs and calculations. I took the monthly index values, generated log scaled returns and here are the equity curve and related statistics (skipped subtracting US 3M T-bills from both return series):

[image]

[image]

In log scale:

[image]

[image]

So, I think GMO's ATM 1M Put Writing strategy has a different profile. And as you can eyeball from the graphs, the original (GMO's) strategy has a beta close to 1. That was my initial concern.

Any further thoughts?

Comment: Theoretically according to the Black Scholes formula a short term put with $S=K$ and $r=0$ has a Delta of $\approx 0.5$. If you do the calculation of Beta empirically for this time period using monthly data from the CME (try it), you find approximately 0.6. The chart you posted clearly shows a Beta less than one: from 1999 to 2003 the orange line goes down a lot, the blue line goes down only a little (about half as much), etc.

Comment: can you please give me the link to CME data? do I need to pay for it?

Comment: Sorry, CBOE not CME The general info page is http://www.cboe.com/products/strategy-benchmark-indexes/putwrite-indexes/cboe-s-p-500-putwrite-index-put there is data at the bottom under "Data on Put Index"

Comment: I got that 0.6 beta, but I think CBOE's Put Index differs from GMO's ATM 1M Put Writing strategy

Comment: Sorry, what's GMO?

Comment: GMO is a private partnership whose sole business is investment management. Check out https://www.gmo.com/north-america/about